# How does one migrate the list of plugins when updating Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I usually install the new (yearly) release of Eclipse by moving the old one, then unpacking the new one in its place. In other words, a completely clean install. Is there a way to import the list of plugin URLs I had in the old Eclipse, so I can choose to update them in the new release?

I realise some of the URLs might be slightly different and require tweaking such as changing "helios" to "indigo"

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Window>Preferences>Install/Update>Available Software Sites`, select all the sites you want to bring with you, and click "export".

You can also export your formatter and cleanup settings through the preferences menu.

Answer (score 1):

Try [copying your settings metadata](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/create-new-eclipse-workspace-w) into the new Eclipse.  Typically that pulls in everything you need such as plugin websites.  You still need to reinstall them however.

Or if you used dropins you can just copy them to the new dropins folder.